# jQuery load first 3 elements for multiple ul lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, show-hide

This question has been asked long ago and answered as well here [jQuery load first 3 elements, click “load more” to display next 5 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736786/jquery-load-first-3-elements-click-load-more-to-display-next-5-elements), but that was for only one `ul` element.

However, I want to know how to do the same thing for multiple elements say I have this instead:

```
<ul id="myList"></ul>
<ul id="myList1"></ul>
<ul id="myList2"></ul>
```

how do I make the javascript for multiple elements in this case??

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
         $('#showLess').show();
        if(x == size_li){
            $('#loadMore').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
        $('#loadMore').show();
         $('#showLess').show();
        if(x == 3){
            $('#showLess').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

any idea how to do that??

Thanks

**Update#1:**

This is my other code part for showmore and showless

```
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div><div id="showLess">show Less</div>
```

**Update#2**

what if classes used instead of ids, would that make it easier?? like this:

```
    <ul class="myList"></ul>
    <ul class="myList"></ul>
    <ul class="myList"></ul>
```

**and each `showmore/Less` can control one of them. so one to one... is that possible???**

Comment: and where is your `#loadMore` and `#showLess` links?

Comment: ok, I will add that to the main post. Thanks for asking

Comment: I suppose that every list has a `loadMore` link?

Comment: That's correct, but I can change that if needed in order to make things work...

Comment: Do you have a `loadMore/showLess` for each `<ul>` or a single `loadMore/showLess` which controls all `<ul>`s?

Comment: I have loadMore/showLess that controls each <ul>. I can change all that if the code requires me to do so... I want each loadMore/showLess to do its own <ul>, but not one controls all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code by using classes instead of ids and a wrapping div; than change accordingly the logic by using element nesting.

Instead of use a variable you can use a HTML attribute to store the current number of showed li for each ul.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".wrapper").each(function (index) {
        $(this).find('.myList li:lt(' + $(this).attr('viewChild') + ')').show();
    });   

    $('.loadMore').click(function () {
        var $myWrapper= $(this).closest('.wrapper');
        var x= parseInt($myWrapper.attr('viewChild'),10);
        var liSize=$myWrapper.find('.myList li').size();        
        x = (x + 5 <= liSize) ? x + 5 : liSize;
        $myWrapper.attr('viewChild',x)
        $myWrapper.find('.myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
        $myWrapper.find('.showLess').show();
        if (x == liSize) {
            $myWrapper.find('.loadMore').hide();
        }
    });

    $('.showLess').click(function () {
        var $myWrapper= $(this).closest('.wrapper');
        var x= $myWrapper.attr('viewChild')
        x = (x - 5 < 0) ? 3 : x - 5;
        $myWrapper.attr('viewChild',x)
        $myWrapper.find('.myList li').not(':lt(' + x + ')').hide();
        $myWrapper.find('.loadMore').show();
        $myWrapper.find('.showLess').show();
        if (x == 3) {
            $myWrapper.find('.showLess').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9gxBT/

Comment: Big Thanks@Irvin Dominin aka Edward. you blew my mind with this great effort. The word Thanks is not enough for the great assistance you provided. wish you all the best!