# Load more on clicking without loading all images first

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created an "overview" container with 100 images. on visit the page will only show one image.

When you click "load more" you will see 1 more, etc.. etc..

```
<div class="overview">
    <div class="block">
        <img src="http://oi50.tinypic.com/4kyccw.jpg"     alt="image_name_01" />
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <img src="http://oi46.tinypic.com/2n208j7.jpg"     alt="image_name_02" />
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <img src="http://oi50.tinypic.com/120me85.jpg"     alt="image_name_03" />
    </div>     
</div>
<div id="loadMore">Load More</div>
```

What I don't want is to load all the 100 images on visit.
but only 1 at the time.
(saving bandwidth if you're on a phone or a tablet) without the use of a database.

I used the "load more" from this question:
[jQuery load first 3 elements, click "load more" to display next 5 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736786/jquery-load-first-3-elements-click-load-more-to-display-next-5-elements)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2qjt9/

Any ideas?

Comment: You try lazy loading? http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery, you could make clicking the button create the new div rather than just showing it using the `.append()` feature. 
http://api.jquery.com/append/

Of course writing html in your javascript might get messy. But luckily you already have it prewritten and working, just copy and paste.

Using `.attr()` you could also give the image in each div a `src` only on click, saving the load bandwidth as well.
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 4):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Ka5uP/)***

The image will only be loaded when it is set to the source of an image. This can be done with `new Image().src="url"` or in css. However, if you just have an array of strings, then none of the urls will be loaded. For example

```
var imgs = [ 
 "http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/133202main_d_reichart_image2.jpg",
 "http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/133202main_d_reichart_image2.jpg",
 "http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/133202main_d_reichart_image2.jpg",
 "http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/133202main_d_reichart_image2.jpg",
 "http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/133202main_d_reichart_image2.jpg",
 "http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/133202main_d_reichart_image2.jpg"
];
```

So I would store your image urls in an array like that and then use them when the time was right. Something I have taken to recently is using html templates. This would mean defining a set of html to populate

```
<div class="picTemplate">
 <img />
</div>
```

And then removing it right at the beginning

```
var template = $('.picTemplate').remove();
```

So that you can later clone it in your event for re-use

```
$("#loadMore").click(function(){
 var index = $('.picDisplay .picTemplate').length;
 if( index >= imgs.length ){
  $(this).remove();
  return;
 }
 var next = template.clone();
 var img = next.find('img')[0];
 img.src = imgs[index];
 img.alt = "some name";
 $('.picDisplay').append(next);
});
```