# Load more every 6 div

Tags: jquery, html

Hello actually how to make a 'Load more' button each 6 div with jquery ?

```
<div>1</div>

<div>2</div>

<div>3</div>

<div>4</div>

<div>5</div>

<div>6</div>

<a href="#" onclick="" > Load More .. </a>
```

and then show the rest div 7, 8, 9, etc

thanks

Comment: Are rest divs present in HTML or you wanna load them via ajax ?

Comment: @user3747421 : Have a look at my answer. Hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery load first 3 elements, click "load more" to display next 5 elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736786/jquery-load-first-3-elements-click-load-more-to-display-next-5-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.append()` in `JQuery` :

Define a function to be called on button click and in the function append divs like this :

`function add(i) {
     $( "#container" ).append( "<div>"+i+"</div>" );
     $( "#container" ).append( "<div>"+(i+1)+"</div>" );
     $( "#container" ).append( "<div>"+(i+2)+"</div>" );
}`

Comment: I guess this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:** If you have fixed number of Divs in your HTML and initially show first 6 and then show rest of them by clicking on button.

```
<div id="container">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
    </div>
    <div id="containerHidden" style="display: none">
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More .. </a>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $('#loadMore').click(function () {
            $('#containerHidden').show();
        });
    </script>
```

**Approach 2:** If you want to append N number of divs dynamically every time by clicking on the button.

```
<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More .. </a>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var counter = parseInt($('#container div').length);
            counter++;
            $('#container').append('<div>' + counter + '</div');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The load more function will load each 6 div, not show or hide, when it 6 or not

Comment: Why the need for a hidden container? Just hide them all, show the first 6 on load and then show more each time

Comment: @user3747421 : what you exactly want ? What I understood is for example you have 10 divs. Initially you want to display only 6 and by clicking on load more button, rest should be displayed. Am I right or not ?

Comment: Why even having a hidden container? Just append 6 more dynamically created containers so enable infinite creation of containers.

Comment: @MagnusBurton : So you mean OP wants to add 6 more divs by clicking on 'Load More' button ?

Comment: Yes. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736786/jquery-load-first-3-elements-click-load-more-to-display-next-5-elements

Comment: @SpiderCode That's correct. Parag's answer seems to do answer the question.

Comment: @MagnusBurton : Have a look at my original answer before editing. :)

Comment: @SpiderCode What your code does is to only show the next 3 rows. As I understand his question "every 6 rows" he wants a show more button to load another 6 rows.. Might be mistaken though

Comment: @MagnusBurton : Right. I guess question seems to be confusing. Any ways thanks for your point :)

Comment: @SpiderCode Yeah question is poorly asked. Sorry if I sounded a bit harsh above, not my intention. Have a great day!