# Wordpress/PHP Loop, Display first 3 items then click to load more

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, loops, foreach

I have created a loop that basically gets all "featured Images" (post thumbnails) & page titles from each page in my WordPress theme and displays them on the front page. That works great, here is the code so far:

```
<?php $args = array(
'sort_order' => 'asc',
'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
'hierarchical' => 1,
'exclude' => '',
'include' => '',
'meta_key' => '',
'meta_value' => '',
'authors' => '',
'child_of' => $post->ID,
'parent' => -1,
'exclude_tree' => '',
'number' => '',
'offset' => 0,
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$pages = get_pages($args); 
?>  

<section id="blog"> 
   <div class="posts">
    <?php foreach ( $pages as $page ) : ?>
    <?php
        $background = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'full' );
    ?>
        <div class="small post" style="background-image: url( '<?php echo $background[0]; ?>' );">

            <a href="<?php the_permalink( $page->ID ); ?>">
                <span class="inside">   
                    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ); ?></h2>
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Problem:**
Because I have 10+ pages on my site, This code outputs all featured images at once. That is too much.

**What I need:**
I would like to limit what I loop out to 3 featured images and then be able to click "View More" to load another "x" amount of featured images.

I have found a perfect example of what I need here: [jQuery load first 3 elements, click "load more" to display next 5 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736786/jquery-load-first-3-elements-click-load-more-to-display-next-5-elements) But it just does not work for me, I am not sure if its because using a JQuery solution for a PHP loop is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress [get_pages()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) add `number`  Sets the number of Pages to list. This causes the SQL LIMIT value to be defined. Default to no LIMIT. 
and For View more you need to do with ajax and jQuery

Please check bellow code

> Add this code in Your page where to display pages listing

```
<?php
$args = array(
'sort_order' => 'asc',
'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
'hierarchical' => 1,
'exclude' => '',
'include' => '',
'meta_key' => '',
'meta_value' => '',
'authors' => '',
'child_of' => $post->ID,
'parent' => -1,
'exclude_tree' => '',
'number' => 3,
'offset' => 0,
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$pages = get_pages($args); 
?>
<section id="blog"> pages
   <div class="posts" id="addviewmoredata">
    <?php foreach ( $pages as $page ) : ?>
    <?php
        $background = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'full' );
    ?>
        <div class="small post" style="background-image: url( '<?php echo $background[0]; ?>' );">

            <a href="<?php the_permalink( $page->ID ); ?>">
                <span class="inside">   
                    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ); ?></h2>
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div><a href="#" id="viewmore" data-id="2">View More</a></div>
</section>
```

> Add this jQuery code in your page where to display pages listing

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on("click","#viewmore",function(){
        var page=jQuery(this).attr("data-id");
        jQuery.ajax('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', {
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                action:'custom_load_more',
                page:page,
                'postid':'<?php echo $post->ID; ?>',
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                //alert(response);
                if(response!="")
                {
                    jQuery("#addviewmoredata").append(response);

                    page++;

                    jQuery("#viewmore").attr("data-id",page);
                }
                else
                {
                    jQuery("#viewmore").remove();
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                if (typeof console === "object") {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            },
            complete: function () {
            }
        }); 
    });

});
</script>
```

> Add this code in your function.php file.

```
function custom_load_more_callback( )
{

        global $wpdb;
        $paged = ( $_REQUEST['page'] ) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1; 
        $offset = ($paged - 1) * 3 + 1;

        $args = array(
        'sort_order' => 'asc',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'exclude' => '',
        'include' => '',
        'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' => '',
        'authors' => '',
        'child_of' => $_REQUEST['postid'],
        'parent' => -1,
        'exclude_tree' => '',
        'number' => 3,
        'offset' => $offset,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
        ); 
        $pages = get_pages($args); 

        ?>  
            <?php if(count($pages)){

            foreach ( $pages as $page ) : ?>
            <?php
                $background = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'full' );
            ?>
                <div class="small post" style="background-image: url( '<?php echo $background[0]; ?>' );">

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink( $page->ID ); ?>">
                        <span class="inside">   
                            <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ); ?></h2>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; } ?>



<?php
die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_load_more', 'custom_load_more_callback'); // Logged-in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_load_more', 'custom_load_more_callback'); // Guest users
```

Comment: Thank you, That works great. There is just one small issue I have. It only lists 2 pages to begin with, then if I change the number, there is still only 2 pages and I get duplicate pages when clicking to view more?

Comment: @lee check in inspect element View more button : data-id is page number is change or not after click on it. it working fine in my project

Comment: @Lee you need to change some code as per your requirement . this code is for only idea how to do this functionality.

Comment: @lee give you site links so i can check it.

Comment: I have it working now, I changed the data ID to 1 and then changed the offset to $offset = ($paged - 1) * 3 + 3; . Now it doesn't skip any pages, Thanks for your help