# How to load iframes with load more button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page which display 4 small iframes and i have one load more button. What I want is: code for load more button that when button is clicked, it will display more iframes 3 or 5. (i will add these).

I have code for a iframe like this below:

```
<div style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
  <iframe style="width: 100%; overflow:hidden; margin-top:-0px;" width="400" height="378" src="" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<button class="btn">Load More</button>
```

I followed this here but it didnot work for me.

[jQuery load first 3 elements, click "load more" to display next 5 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736786/jquery-load-first-3-elements-click-load-more-to-display-next-5-elements?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: USE AJAX remove the iframe idea from your mind. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iframe creater object I created below

initialize the iframe object

add all iframe links when initializing iframe object

add parent container you would like ALL iframeS to be inside. In my example is the body of the document

add an event listener to button which will trigger iframe method name `add_iframe()`

```js
counter = 0

function iframe_creator(parent, src_array) {
  this.src_array = src_array;
  this.parent = parent;
  this.template = '\
  <iframe style="width: 100%; overflow:hidden; margin-top:-0px;" width="400" height="378" src="" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>\
';
  this.add_iframe = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      if (counter < this.src_array.length) {

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = this.template;
        div.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = this.src_array[counter];
        div.style = "margin:0px; padding:0px;"
        this.parent.appendChild(div);
        ++counter;
      } //end if

    }

  }

}
create_frame = new iframe_creator(document.body, ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature']);
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  create_frame.add_iframe()
})
```

```css
iframe {
  border: solid black;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">
  press
</button>
```

Comment: thanks, its good. Only one thing, can we load 5 iframe one button is pressed?

Comment: if you want to change the number of iframes just take out 5 from ***for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) *** and put in any number..

Comment: Perfect. Thanks alot!

Comment: can you put  all codes in a jsfiddle and save it..or send me the link to the website?..

Comment: have you taken out document.body and replace it with your div object. from  ***create_frame = new iframe_creator(document.body...***. for example document.getElementById('whatever_id')

Comment: try it and you will see..document.getElementById('whatver_name')...put id of div instead of 'whatever_name'

Comment: *** <iframe style="width: 100%; overflow:hidden; margin-top:-0px;" width="400" height="378" src="" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>\ ***  change value for height and width in this line

Answer (score 1):

First, give your `<div>` where you want to place your `<iframe>`-Tags in an ID so that you can select and interact with it using JS.

Then use JS to create a function which will add a new `<iframe>`-Tag to your wrapping div.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgdKQp

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<button onclick="loadMore()">Load More</button>
```

JS:

```
function loadMore() {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper'); // Get wrapper
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); // Create new iframe
  wrapper.appendChild(iframe); // Set iframe as child of wrapper

  // Set the initial url like this:
  iframe.contentWindow.document.location.href = 'http://codepen.io/';
}
```