# Load website data on scrolling Down in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

my question is that i have a structure of website as

```
    <div class="span">.......</div>
    <div class="span">.......</div>
    <div class="span">.......</div>
    <div class="span">.......</div>
    <div class="span">.......</div>
```

these are 100+ loaded form database and working fine.I just want that initially it will show only 5
  
and then when user scroll down they will show more.
thanks

Comment: Normally called infinite scrolling

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: i have posted my full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  size_li = $(".listingcall .span6").size();
  size_li = $(".listingcall .span6").size();
  x=3;
  $('.listingcall .span6:lt('+x+')').show();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
$('.listingcall .span6:lt('+x+')').show();
      }    
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link:

[jQuery load first 3 elements, click "load more" to display next 5 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736786/jquery-load-first-3-elements-click-load-more-to-display-next-5-elements)

There is also an example.

Comment: in your case, you'll need to put an event on your scrolling, so at like 80% of your div, load more for example.