# Show More / Show Less every 3 elements with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load the first 3 list items each `div.content`,  then show the next 3 items when the user clicks the "SHOW MORE"

And When the user click "SHOW LESS", back to display block the first 3 list

I see another answer
ref. [jQuery load first 3 elements, click “load more” to display next 5 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736786/jquery-load-first-3-elements-click-load-more-to-display-next-5-elements?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But I can't be apply to my code

How can I best achieve this?

Note: Sorry my English is not good.

This My HTML

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">1</div>
  <div class="items">2</div>
  <div class="items">3</div>
  <div class="items">4</div>
  <div class="items">5</div>
  <div class="items">6</div>
  <div class="items">7</div>
  <div class="items">8</div>
  <div class="items">9</div>
  <a href="#" id="ShowMore">SHOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#" id="ShowLess">SHOW LESS</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">11</div>
  <div class="items">12</div>
  <div class="items">13</div>
  <div class="items">14</div>
  <div class="items">15</div>
  <div class="items">16</div>
  <div class="items">17</div>
  <div class="items">18</div>
  <div class="items">19</div>
  <a href="#" id="ShowMore">SHOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#" id="ShowLess">SHOW LESS</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">21</div>
  <div class="items">22</div>
  <div class="items">23</div>
  <div class="items">24</div>
  <div class="items">25</div>
  <div class="items">26</div>
  <div class="items">27</div>
  <div class="items">28</div>
  <div class="items">29</div>
  <a href="#" id="ShowMore">SHOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#" id="ShowLess">SHOW LESS</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Identifiers in HTML must be __unique__.Start with making your HTML document valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following snippet shows how to `show next three items` on clicking show more and `collapse back to the first three items` on clicking show less.

Changed the **ID** to **CLASS** as this is the right way to so it. Multiple elements should not have same id.

**Explanation**
First hide all items except first three using the following selector:
 `.content .items:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+3)`

Then on clicking Show More button find the next three hidden items with the following selector:
`.items:not(:visible):lt(3)`
This selector selects the first three items which are not visible.

Finally on Show Less, hide all elements and show only the first three as before.

```js
$(function(){
$('.content .items').hide();
$('.content .items:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+3)').show();

$('.ShowMore').click(function(){
$(this).closest('.content').find('.items:not(:visible):lt(3)').show();
})

$('.ShowLess').click(function(){
$(this).closest('.content').find('.items').hide();
$(this).closest('.content').find('.items:lt(3)').show();
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">1</div>
  <div class="items">2</div>
  <div class="items">3</div>
  <div class="items">4</div>
  <div class="items">5</div>
  <div class="items">6</div>
  <div class="items">7</div>
  <div class="items">8</div>
  <div class="items">9</div>
  <a href="#" class="ShowMore">SHOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#" class="ShowLess">SHOW LESS</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">11</div>
  <div class="items">12</div>
  <div class="items">13</div>
  <div class="items">14</div>
  <div class="items">15</div>
  <div class="items">16</div>
  <div class="items">17</div>
  <div class="items">18</div>
  <div class="items">19</div>
  <a href="#" class="ShowMore">SHOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#" class="ShowLess">SHOW LESS</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">21</div>
  <div class="items">22</div>
  <div class="items">23</div>
  <div class="items">24</div>
  <div class="items">25</div>
  <div class="items">26</div>
  <div class="items">27</div>
  <div class="items">28</div>
  <div class="items">29</div>
  <a href="#" class="ShowMore">SHOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#" class="ShowLess">SHOW LESS</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an adaptation of the code from the referenced answer:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.items').hide();
  $('.content').find('.items:lt(3)').show();
  
  $('.ShowMore').click(function(ev) {
    $(ev.currentTarget).parent().find('.items').show();
  });

  $('.ShowLess').click(function(ev) {
    $(ev.currentTarget).parent().find('.items').not(':lt(3)').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">1</div>
  <div class="items">2</div>
  <div class="items">3</div>
  <div class="items">4</div>
  <div class="items">5</div>
  <div class="items">6</div>
  <div class="items">7</div>
  <div class="items">8</div>
  <div class="items">9</div>
  <a href="#" class="ShowMore">SHOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#" class="ShowLess">SHOW LESS</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">11</div>
  <div class="items">12</div>
  <div class="items">13</div>
  <div class="items">14</div>
  <div class="items">15</div>
  <div class="items">16</div>
  <div class="items">17</div>
  <div class="items">18</div>
  <div class="items">19</div>
  <a href="#" class="ShowMore">SHOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#" class="ShowLess">SHOW LESS</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">21</div>
  <div class="items">22</div>
  <div class="items">23</div>
  <div class="items">24</div>
  <div class="items">25</div>
  <div class="items">26</div>
  <div class="items">27</div>
  <div class="items">28</div>
  <div class="items">29</div>
  <a href="#" class="ShowMore">SHOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#" class="ShowLess">SHOW LESS</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- The identifier must be unique, this approach changes those ids into class.
- You can use this selector to hide the rest of `.items`: `.items:gt(2)`
- Those links (less and more) have a `data-attribute` to indicate the action.

*This approach doesn't hide the Show less nor Show more links*

```js
var parentSelector = "div.content",
    showItemsSelector = ".items:gt(2)",
    showLessSelector = ".ShowMore,.ShowLess";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(parentSelector).each(showItemsHandler);
  $(showLessSelector).on('click', showHideHandler);
});

function showHideHandler() {
 if ($(this).data('action') === 'show') $(this).closest(parentSelector).children('.items').show();
 else showItemsHandler.bind($(this).closest(parentSelector))();
}

function showItemsHandler() {
  $(this).children(showItemsSelector).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">1</div>
  <div class="items">2</div>
  <div class="items">3</div>
  <div class="items">4</div>
  <div class="items">5</div>
  <div class="items">6</div>
  <div class="items">7</div>
  <div class="items">8</div>
  <div class="items">9</div>
  <a href="#" data-action='show' class="ShowMore">SHOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#" data-action='hide' class="ShowLess">SHOW LESS</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">11</div>
  <div class="items">12</div>
  <div class="items">13</div>
  <div class="items">14</div>
  <div class="items">15</div>
  <div class="items">16</div>
  <div class="items">17</div>
  <div class="items">18</div>
  <div class="items">19</div>
  <a href="#" data-action='show' class="ShowMore">SHOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#" data-action='hide' class="ShowLess">SHOW LESS</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="items">21</div>
  <div class="items">22</div>
  <div class="items">23</div>
  <div class="items">24</div>
  <div class="items">25</div>
  <div class="items">26</div>
  <div class="items">27</div>
  <div class="items">28</div>
  <div class="items">29</div>
  <a href="#" data-action='show' class="ShowMore">SHOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#" data-action='hide' class="ShowLess">SHOW LESS</a>
</div>
```